# If l = lcm(a,b) and l=pa and l=qb, prove that gcd (p,q) = 1

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I am trying to prove the following:
Let l = lcm$(a,b)$ and write l=pa and l=qb. Prove that gcd (p,q) = 1.

One of my students wrote his thoughts below.

[image]

I know it is probably not that difficult, I just think I am not seeing something.

Thanks for your help.

Source: (from Cambridge's Math HL Discrete Option, page 23)

Comment: I like your student's answer.  Creative and correct.

Comment: use latex to write questions

Comment: This is simply the definition of LCM.

Comment: <humor> This is not a Venn diagram, these are not circles, these are factorial rings :p

Comment: @E.Eckstein: Wait... you have students, but are unable to understand those few elementary lines? Holy cow, where is Education going towards?

Answer (score 1):

$\text{If $\ell = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$, $\ell=pa$ and $\ell=qb$, then prove that $\gcd(p,q) = 1$}$

$\gcd(a,b) = \dfrac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)} = \dfrac{ab}{\ell}$

\begin{align}
   g &= \gcd(p,q) \\
   ga &= \gcd(\ell, qa) \\
   ga &= \gcd(qb,qa) \\
   ga &= q \ \gcd(a,b) \\
   ga &= \dfrac{qab}{\ell} \\
   ga &= a \\
   g &= 1
\end{align}

Comment: This is some kind of circular proof, I'm not sure we can simply show $ab=\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ without using the result we want to prove.

Comment: @zwim - If you look at the exponents in the prime factorization, it's just using min(a,b) + max(a,b)=a+b. Even if you're right, I think (hope?) it can be circumvented.

Comment: In that case, it is ok. I have checked this in a book: when working only in an integral domain and $l=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ exists, then $g=\gcd(a,b)$ exists too and verify $ab=lg$. So the proof that uses prime factors and exponents in a UFD is more advanced. Anyway, it is 100% legit in the context of integers, I just wanted to point out it may be a circular reasoning in weaker rings.

Comment: @zwim  Yes, I assumed a UFD. I wouldn't have if you provided some more context. But thanks because now I have to try and solve that problem too. :)

Comment: We had already proved ab=gcd(a,b) x lcm(a,b), so this proof is valid. It was really clear for the students as well. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(p,q)\ge 1$ then $p=dp'$ and $q=dq'$

Now $l=dp'a=dq'b$

so $d$ divides $l\qquad$ i.e. $\quad l'=\frac ld$ is an integer.

But $l'=p'a=q'b$ so it is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$

By definition of the lcm, then $l'\ge l\iff\frac ld\ge l\iff d\le 1$, so $d=1$.

Comment: Thanks for this - it is really clear and elegant. I never thought about comparing the common multiple and lcm.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Venn diagram is clever.  I don't know if s/he came up with it on her/his own or if this was how s/he was taught.

But given two numbers $a$ and $b$ we can divide those into three factors.

$\frac {a}{\gcd(a,b)} = m$ which is the product of all the prime factors of $a$ that are not shared with $b$.

$\frac {b}{\gcd(a,b)} = n$ which is the product of all the prime factors of $b$ that are not shared with $a$.

And $\gcd(a,b) = o$ which is the product of all the prime factors shared by both.

And fundamental observations:

$\gcd (m,n) = 1$ (as they have no factors in common.)  And $a = m*o$ and $b = n*o$.

And the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is $m*n*o = a*n = b*m$.

........

And ... everything falls into place.  $lcm = l = pa   = an$

$lcm = l = qb  = b*m$.

So $p=n$ and $q= m$.  Ad we know $\gcd(m,n) =1$.

Comment: The Venn Diagram was used on an earlier proof of gcd(a,b) x lcm(a,b) = ab, so it wasn't completely original, but he was the only own in class who successfully did this. Also, thanks for your proof - I think it is really good for teaching proof to the students, since one of the techniques I encourage is to write down all observations.